# How to create a custom WooCommerce WordPress input field and add it to the registration and then check the value the user entered

Tags: php, wordpress, input, woocommerce, registration

I am really in need of some help, I am trying to create a custom user field to add in my Wordpress website's registration. I use WooCommerce. I would also like to see the value the user entered in that input. Supposedly we call that input "Phone number". How can I add the input field, how can I also check the value which the user entered? In WordPress I use New User Approve and Cimy User Extra Fields. I've also actually added the fields in the functions.php file.

```
function wooc_extra_register_fields() {?>
   <p class="form-row form-row-wide">
   <label for="reg_billing_phone"><?php _e( 'Телефон', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
   <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_phone" id="reg_billing_phone" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_phone'] ); ?>" />
   </p>
```

So yes, the inputs are added, but I cannot see the values the users enter in that input, how can I see them? I would like to see them in the Users section from the Wordpress dashboard or the Users Extended. If you have a better idea, please tell it to me, please. This is how the registration looks, and as you can see I added the phone number input field, but the problem is, how can I see the value the user enters in it after he registers?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can helps: [Woocommerce phone field validation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595775/woocommerce-phone-field-validation-issue/46596451#46596451)